# EF FromSql() with related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata

Disclaimer: these requirements are not set by me, unless this is an impossible task I cannot convince my boss otherwise.

Let's say we have two entities: `Item` and `ItemTranslation`.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ItemTranslation> Translations { get; set; }
}

public class ItemTranslation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CultureId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

The requirement is that `Item`.`Description` should be filled in based on a language selected by default, but also allowing it to be specified based on what the user wants. The `Item`.`Description` column doesn't actually exist in the database.

In SQL this would be easy: all you have to do is query both tables like so

```
SELECT [Item].[Id], [ItemTranslation].[Description], [Item].[ParentId] 
FROM [Item] 
LEFT JOIN [ItemTranslation] ON [Item].[Id] = [ItemTranslation].[ItemId]  
WHERE [CultureId] = {cultureId}
```

Or use an OUTER APPLY depending on your implementation. I have added this query to the `.FromSql()` function built in Entity Framework.

Put this all together in an OData API and this all works fine for one `Item`. However as soon as you start using $expand (which behind the scenes is a sort of .Include()) it no longer works. The query being sent to the database for the related entities no longer holds the SQL which I specified in `.FromSql()`. Only the first query does. On top of this when you would query an `Item` from a different controller e.g. `ItemTranslation` this would also no longer work since `.FromSql()` is only applied in the other controller.

I could write a query interceptor which simply replaces the generated SQL by Entity Framework and replaces `FROM [Item]` with `FROM [Item] LEFT JOIN [ItemTranslation] ON [Item].[Id] = [ItemTranslation].[ItemId] WHERE [CultureId] = {cultureId}` but I wonder if there is a better implementation than that. Perhaps even a redesign in models. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: That SQL actually isn't valid since `Description` and `Id` are both ambiguous between the two tables.

Comment: Why are you stepping away of the SQL generated by using EF in a more conventional fashion? (...or why are you using `FromSql` instead of LINQ?)

Comment: ...there doesn't appear to be anything in your requirements that would necessitate falling back to crafting your own SQL. As you are discovering, doing so comes with disadvantages.

Comment: @spender What do you mean, I have to fill in Item.Description based on a CultureId the user is passing. How would I accomplish that without .FromSql() and within an OData API context meaning I have to return IQueryable<T>?

Comment: You do know that LINQ queries against EF also return `IQueryable<T>`?

Answer (score 0):

*FromSql* has some [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#limitations). I suspect this is the reason why *Include* won't work.

But once you use EF, why are you messing with SQL? What difficulties does that query have which prevents you from doing it in LINQ? Left join maybe?

```
from item in ctx.Items
from itemTranslation in ctx.ItemTranslations.Where(it => it.Item.Id == item.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
where itemTranslation.CultureId == cultureId
select new { item.Id, itemTranslation.Description, ParentId = item.Parent.Id };
```

**Update**

Going over the issue again, I see a further problem. *Include* will only work on an *IQueryable<T>* where T is an entity whose navigation properties are mapped properly. Now, from this perspective, it doesn't matter if you use *FromSql* or LINQ if it produces an *IQueryable* of some projection instead of an entity, *Include* won't work for obvious reasons.

To be able to include *ItemTranslation* entities, your action method should look something like this:

```
[Queryable]
public IQueryable<Item> GetItems()
{
    return db.Items;
}
```

So the framework can perform *$expand* on the *IQueryable<Item>* you return. However, this will include all item translations, not just the ones with the desired culture. If I get it correctly, this is your core issue.

It's obvious as well that you cannot apply this culture filter to an *IQueryable<Item>*. But you shouldn't do that as this is achieved by [$filter](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/#FilterSystemQueryOption) in OData:

```
GET https://.../Items/$expand=Translations&$filter=Translations/CultureId eq culture
```

Comment: OData requires an IQueryable<T> resource. It also allows passing $expand which will query the related data and perform a sort of .Include() behind the scenes. This means that it's possible to query Item from the ItemTranslation controller, which will not have this LINQ in it.

Comment: Both your FromSql and my LINQ code return an IQueryable<T>. However there are differences what you can do with them - regarding e.g. query composition. Did you try the LINQ I suggested instead of FromSql? And what is not clear to me what does this all have to do with controllers?

Comment: Yes that is essentially almost what the requirement is except that the Item.Description should also contain the Description taken from ItemTranslation where the CultureId equals what the user passes to the API. That is the hardest part.

Comment: Why do you need *Item.Description* at all? You have that piece of information in *Item.Translations[0].Description* (when $expand and $filter for *CultureId* is applied as shown above). The problem is you try to flatten your object hierarchy essentially turning your *Item* entity into a DTO. I repeat: $expand needs a properly mapped entity to be able to do its *Include* magic under the hood. So you either return flat objects and forget about $expand (but why to use OData then?) or you return an entity and $expand will work as expected. You cannot have both at the same time.

Comment: You may be able to workaround this using views or similar features of EF but I think this would rather fall into the category of hacking and would defeat the purpose of OData.

Comment: I'm sorry. As it says in the disclaimer this is not my choice. The idea is that the end user does not have to expand a level deeper and a fallback language can be set, meaning if that translation isn't found it can default to the first found.